# Compile Error: Calling function 'BreadcrumbModule', function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, breadcrumbs

I am using Angular2-crumbs in my project while I have implemented as they described in their github repo [here](https://github.com/emilol/angular-crumbs/tree/angular2-crumbs/demo). Everything working perfectly as expected but when I tried to do `ng build --prod` I am getting following error:

**Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'BreadcrumbModule', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function**

So to resolve that I had modified my root.module.ts as below:

```
imports: [
        CoreModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        //BreadcrumbModule.forRoot(), // <-- commented this part
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: translateFactory,
                deps: [Http]
            }
        }),
        RootRoutingModule,
        BreadcrumbModule // <-- included this part

    ]
```

But it still didn't resolve the error. I have followed some of the github posts which says that if 3rd party library is not AOT compatible then you get above error and I tried to use their [workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4647) below (added to tsconfig.json):

```
"paths": { "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"] }
```

and again there is no luck to get this resolve. If anyone has some idea about this please let me know because I have stuck at this point.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out what was the problem. [Angular2-crumbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-crumbs) works only with angular2 project. Since my project is `Angular4` so I have uninstall the `Angular2-crumbs` and install the [Angular-crumbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-crumbs) which is `Angular4` compatible.

It's compiling without any problem.